# Pass C# float array to Javascript in CefSharp

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp

I am developing in a WPF project and am using CefSharp.wpf to connect to my html/javascript script. The script is locally on my pc.
Currently, I have to convert my C# float array to a string, which takes a long time (192ms).
It takes this long because the array has a length of over 200000.
The main problem is that this Array has to be sent 30 times per Second, with different values each time.

My Idea was to send the pointer to the array location to the website  so it can always get the newest version directly, but I have not found a solution yet.
Does anyone have an Idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: @evolutionxbox do you have another idea to increase the speed I can pass the data?

Comment: What you want sounds quite ambitious, like you expect an embedded browser to be able to plot live waveforms coming from .NET? That said, have a look at **Protobuf**, it's a binary data exchange format which is more efficient than JSON, or whatever other string format presumably. See this basic performance comparison: https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/protobuf-in-c-net-part-4-performance-comparisons/

Comment: "this Array has to be sent 30 times per Second, with different values each time." Is a redesign of your architecture an option? Can the task that requires you to recieve such a considerable amount of data in a short time be performed directly in the local machine, and then send *only* the results that you actually want to present to the website's users? I mean, even if you require some form of "real time" data in the website, you can dumb it down to a much manageable rate like 1 update per second.

Comment: It is not, at least not that I'm aware of. These are the new positions for objects I have to draw to the screen, so I need all the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found was to use a web socket server. For this I used Fleck.
C#:

```
HttpListener httpListener;
WebSocketServer webSocketServer;
List<IWebSocketConnection> connectedSockets = new List<IWebSocketConnection>();
webSocketServer = new WebSocketServer("ws://127.0.0.1:8181");
webSocketServer.Start(socket =>
{
    socket.OnOpen = () =>
    {
        connectedSockets.Add(socket);
        ExampleSendingFloatArray();
    };
    socket.OnClose = () =>
    {
        connectedSockets.Remove(socket);
    };
});
private void SendFloatArrayToClients(float[] data)
{
    using MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    using BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(ms);

    for(int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        writer.Write(data[i]);
    }
   
    byte[] byteArray = ms.ToArray();
    foreach (var socket in connectedSockets)
    {
        socket.Send(byteArray);
    }
}
private void ExampleSendingFloatArray()
{
    float[] floatArray = new float[217088*3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        SendFloatArrayToClients(floatArray);
    }
}
```

Javascript:

```
socket.onmessage = (event) => {
    if (!(event.data instanceof Blob)) {
        return;
    }

    const fileReader = new FileReader();

    fileReader.onload = () => {
        threeHandler.sensor.pointCloud.UpdateDephtmap(new Float32Array(fileReader.result));
    };

    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(event.data);

};
```

Using this code, sending the array 30 times per second is possible.
This code is not yet optimised. If I find a way to optimize it, I'll update it here.

Answer (score 3):

You can use CefSharp's `RegisterJsObject` method to bind a C# object to JavaScript, and then access the float array directly from JavaScript.

```
public class FloatArrs
{
    public float[] FloatArr { get; set; }
}
```

```
FloatArrs floatArrs = new FloatArrs();
chromiumWebBrowser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Settings.LegacyBindingEnabled= true;
chromiumWebBrowser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Register("myFloatArrs", floatArrs, isAsync:false);
```

You can access like `var arr = myFloatArrs.FloatArr;`

And update

```
floatArras.FloatArr = updatedFloatArr;
chromiumWebBrowser.ExecuteScriptAsync("updateFloatArr()");
```

In your JavaScript code, define a function `updateFloatArr` that reacts to the array update:

```
// JavaScript function to handle the array update
function updateFloatArr() {
    var myFloatArr = myFloatArrs.FloatArr;
}
```

This way, you're directly accessing the float array from JavaScript without the need to convert it to a string.

Comment: Not sure how this got upvotes as this will throw an exception on any recent version of `CefSharp`, specifically a `NotImplementedException` as `RegisterJsObject` was replaced. It would be `browser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Register("myFloatArrs", floatArrs, isAsync: false);`. `LegacyJavascriptBindingEnabled` is no longer a global option. It's per browser. `browser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Settings.LegacyBindingEnabled = true;`. This code hasn't been valid for a number of years.

Comment: @amaitland, Thanks for your advice. Could you recommend new method?

Comment: Is this code your using currently or code you've found randomly and posted? The method hasn't changed fundamentally, the code is just years out of date.  If you make the changes I've suggested then it should work the same

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.Test/JavascriptBinding/IntegrationTests.cs#L163 https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#3-how-do-you-expose-a-net-class-to-javascript

Comment: While this code works, my testing shows it actually is slower, taking >500ms to access the array